# Scala: Null and Nothing

Tags: scala, types

It is said that `scala.Nothing` and `scala.Null` are bottom classes and they extend every other `AnyRef` classes. consider the below snippet

```
class Test() {}
val test:Test = null
```

So for the statement to succeeded either `Null` should extend the custom class `Test` (i.e. Test is a super type of Null) or the type system should make exceptions of not throwing type mismatch error for `scala.Null`. How scala ensures that these two classes always extend any other AnyRef descendants classes in scala ?

Comment: `Null` and `Nothing` are explicitly special-cased in the compiler AIUI - is that what you're asking?

Comment: yes @Imm any idea how it works? does compiler only checks if the LHS is AnyRef descendant and doesn't follow the conventional type check?

Comment: Something like this: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/3c7b1e3d953703582aae81506f8b27732a603bfe/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BTypes.scala#L320-L326

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically compiler explicitly handles bottom type conformity, like in [the excerpt from scala compiler](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/3c7b1e3d953703582aae81506f8b27732a603bfe/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BTypes.scala#L320-L326):

```
...
} else if (isNullType) {
  if (other.isNothingType) false
  else if (other.isPrimitive) false
  else true // Null conforms to all classes (except Nothing) and arrays.
} else if (isNothingType) {
  true
} else other match {
...
```

Comment: so as said in the documentation Null and Nothing are not exactly Bottom classes and they don't extend all AnyRef classes (if they did they would have all the methods of all its superclass and it would be super messy). This stated behavior is just mimicked by the type system.

Comment: I think `Nothing` is used only as a type, not a class at all, because there cannot be instances of `Nothing`. `Null` is more "material" in this sence, but still not a true class.